# Merge many pairs of data together into separate data sets

Tags: r, merge

I have about 100 dataset pairs that need to be merged into single data sets, I have looked at posts that show how to merge many data sets together at once (e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091303/simultaneously-merge-multiple-data-frames-in-a-list) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34847580/r-merge-multiple-pairs-of-dataframes)), but my issue is unique. My real-world data are stored on my hard drive and are similarly named (e.g., `household2010`, `household2011`, `household2012` and `person2010`, `person2011`, `person2012`. They don't need to be loaded into the global environment.Example below.

Working data:

```
library(tidyverse)

household2010 <- tribble(
~id, ~var2, ~var3, ~var4, ~var5,
"1",   "1",   "1",   "a",   "d",
"2",   "2",   "2",   "b",   "e",
"3",   "3",   "3",   "c",   "f"
)

person2010 <- tribble(
~id, ~var6, ~var7,
"1",   "1",   "1",
"2",   "2",   "2",
"3",   "3",   "3",
"4",   "4",   "4"
)

household2011 <- tribble(
~id, ~var8, ~var9, ~var10,
"1",   "1",   "1",    "1",
"2",   "2",   "2",    "2",
"3",   "3",   "3",    "3",
"4",   "4",   "4",    "4"
)

person2011 <- tribble(
~id, ~var11, ~var12, ~var13,
"1",   "1",   "1",    "1",
"2",   "2",   "2",    "2",
"3",   "3",   "3",    "3",
"4",   "4",   "4",    "4",
"5",   "5",   "5",    "5"
 )
```

I need to merge `household2010` with `person2010` and create a new dataset called `hhperson2010`. I need to do this to `household2011` and `person2011` too. Individually  I could do:

```
hhperson2010 <- left_join(household2010, person2010, by = "id")

hhperson2011 <- left_join(household2011, person2011, by = "id")
```

This gets clunky when I have over a 100 data pairs. Can I use `lapply` to have it go through a list of the data sets and merge? Something like:

```
dflist1 <- list(household2010, household2011)

dflist2 <- list(person2011,    person2011)

lapply(function(x) left_join(dflist, dflist2, by = "id")
```

Comment: Thanks @d.b., but this doesn't work as it creates one dataset. I need to the pairs to be merged into separate datasets.

Comment: Why don't you do it at inhale. These 100 tables come from somewhere. Are you importing them from files? `lapply` there and never have 100 objects in the memory. Give us a little more idea of data provenance, so we can suggest smarter way of avoiding 100 variables in the global environment

Comment: The files are all RData objects stored on my hard drive (edited my example above). If I could do it all at once without actually loading them into the global environment, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
years <- 2010:2011
result <- lapply(years, 
              function(x) left_join(get(paste0("household", x)), 
                                    get(paste0("person", x)), 
                                    "id"))

names(result) <- paste0("household", years)
```

Comment: Thanks @PoGibas, but this saves an empty file. I wish the `save` command would accept something like you have. I prefer to save the files as `Rdata` rather than `RDS`.

Comment: I removed the need to `save` the datasets, if that makes it easier.

Comment: @scottsmith I updated my answer with saving result to list and naming list entries with wanted names. You can save this list as single object or extract entries with `result[["householdYEAR"]]`

Comment: Thanks @PoGibas, this works! Following @dmi3kno's suggestion, is there a way to modify your code to call a list of files from my hard drive so I don't have to load `household201x` and `person201x` files into the global environment? Maybe using something like `files <- list.files(pattern = "household*.RData)` for both the `household` and `person` files and put that into the `function`?

Comment: @scottsmith 1. write a loop to iterate over one year at a time; 2. save all year data into a single tibble object.

Comment: @scottsmith, are those bunch of .Rdata files?

Answer (score 0):

```
just an alternate solution:
years <- c("2010", "2011", "2014") 

for (x in years){
  result <- merge(get(paste0("household", x)), get(paste0("person", x)), "id")
  names <- paste0("household", x)
  print(names)
  print(result)
}
```

you can make a choice between loop or lapply depending on your further processing if any. In case, you don't have any more to do with your dataset, I think lapply would just solve the purpose.

Comment: Thanks @Vishal786btc, but this I would still have to manually do `hhperson2010 = merge(x = df1, y = df2, by = "id", all.x = TRUE)` for each year, and I am trying to avoid that.

Comment: This is exactly want OP want to avoid

Comment: oh okay. Thanks @PoGibas for pointing that. your answer looks good then. I'll fix mine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it with `tidyverse` and list-columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

env2listcol <- function(rdata_file)
{
  e <- new.env()
  load(rdata_file, envir = e)
  # since you know that there's only 1 df in each environment
  as.list.environment(e)[[1]] 
}

# assuming files are stored in `input` folder
dir("input", full.names = T) %>% as_tibble() %>% 
  # split the path
  separate(value, into=c("dir", "file", "ext"), remove=FALSE) %>% 
  # get the category and the key in separate columns
  extract(file, into=c("key", "year"), regex="([a-z]+)(\\d+)") %>% 
  # file path by category by year, remove unnecessary columns
  spread(key, value) %>% select(-dir, -ext) %>% 
  # extract dataframes from environments, and join them
  mutate(household=map(household, env2listcol),
         person=map(person, env2listcol),
         joined=map2(household, person, left_join)) %>% 
  # rbind joined tables, although you could pull(joined) or imap over it
  unnest(joined)

#> # A tibble: 7 x 14
#>    year    id  var2  var3  var4  var5  var6  var7  var8  var9 var10 var11 var12 var13
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1  2010     1     1     1     a     d     1     1  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
#> 2  2010     2     2     2     b     e     2     2  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
#> 3  2010     3     3     3     c     f     3     3  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
#> 4  2011     1  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>     1     1     1     1     1     1
#> 5  2011     2  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>     2     2     2     2     2     2
#> 6  2011     3  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>     3     3     3     3     3     3
#> 7  2011     4  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>     4     4     4     4     4     4
```

You decide what you want to do with it. You may write it back to R objects (please, please, please... use Rds instead). You may write it back into a single table (I believe it is MUCH easier to handle going forward). You can probably even export it as json.